# Weird cluster file share behaviour

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-cluster

I have a windows server 2016 cluster. Depending on where the file share role is hosted, I am unable to access the unc path of the file share on the node where the role is hosted, but I am able to access it on any other remote host.

For instance, my cluster physical hostnames are host x and host y. If the role is active on host x, the virtual file share unc path can only be accessed on host y successfully. It will throw a "Windows cannot access \virtual name\some path" You do not have permissions to access ... if I access it on host x.

Was wondering if anyone have met with such an issue before and how to solve this.

Comment: Did you prestage the cluster in AD? Might be helpful: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/prestage-cluster-adds